# Extract specific object from a list of sequences in python

Tags: algorithm, python-2.7, sequences, fpm

I implemented fpm algorithm to find the rules from the activity data, I have the output data in the format.

```
for itemset in find_frequent_itemsets(dataset, 0.1,include_support=True):
    print itemset
```

The following is the output of the above code:

```
([u'Global Connect Village'], 28)
([u'Terminal 2', u'Global Connect Village'], 1)
([u'VivoCity', u'Global Connect Village'], 1)
([u'Universal Studios Singapore', u'VivoCity', u'Global Connect Village'], 1)
([u'Universal Studios Singapore', u'Global Connect Village'], 2)
([u'Orchard Gateway', u'Global Connect Village'], 2)
([u'Chinatown', u'Global Connect Village'], 2)
([u'Singapore Changi Airport (SIN)', u'Chinatown', u'Global Connect Village'], 2)
([u'Fragrance Hotel', u'Global Connect Village'], 2)
([u'Singapore Changi Airport (SIN)', u'Fragrance Hotel', u'Global Connect Village'], 1)
([u'Singapore', u'Global Connect Village'], 3)
([u'Singapore Changi Airport (SIN)', u'Singapore', u'Global Connect Village'], 1)
([u"McDonald's", u'Global Connect Village'], 4)
([u'Singapore Changi Airport (SIN)', u"McDonald's", u'Global Connect Village'], 1)
```

I want to extract only those values which are having higher support and contains three or more objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use [`filter`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#filter) and [`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#sorted):

```
MIN_LOCS = 3
itemset = find_frequent_itemsets(dataset, 0.1,include_support=True
itemset = sorted(filter(lambda it: len(it[0]) >= MIN_LOCS, itemset), key=lambda it: it[1])
```

Then you can pick the top elements you want:

```
itemset_top_5 = itemset[:5]
```

If you want to include a minimum support value just adapt the filtering as needed:

```
itemset = sorted(filter(lambda it: len(it[0]) >= MIN_LOCS and it[1] >= MIN_SUPPORT, itemset),
                 key=lambda it: it[1])
```

Comment: but, i ant t extract the trios, the patterns which have three or more locations

Comment: can you help in that

Comment: @Shivam Ah, sorry, I misunderstood, I've updated the answer.

Comment: i did it, by this same logic, i am now wondering to use AND to include min support too.

Comment: just a last question, i can convert it (the final sorted object) to pandas dataframe, you can type, here, your first answer was all that i need, I am able to do it now. many thanks

Comment: @Shivam How would the dataframe be, one column with a list and one column with support? Because I don't think one column per item would work since you have different numbers of items.

Comment: yes, i agree with you, the same. 2 colm dataframe. sequence and support. many thanks for you time

Comment: @Shivam Try something like `pd.DataFrame(dict(zip(('Items', 'Support'), zip(*itemset))))`.